# Issue with Greek Libreoffice

Tags: libreoffice

I have an issue where I open a .csv file in Libre office that I have been working on for a month now and for some reason today the Greek letters do not display correctly they show as a question mark . Is there anything I can do to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anything I can do to fix this issue ?

Your `.csv` is read using the wrong character set. It may be read as "Unicode (UTF-8)" but have been encoded using another character set.

The "Text import" dialog allows to select a different character set to import the file. There are many character sets, so find the correct one by trial and error is almost no option. There are, however, tools that allow to guess the character set used to encode the file:

The `file` command:

```
$ file -i export.csv 
export.csv: text/csv; charset=us-ascii
```

In this example, the file does not contain any extended character: it is pure us-asci.

The `encguess` command (`perl` package)

```
$ encguess data.csv
data.csv    UTF-8
```

suggesting the file is UTF-8 encoded.

You then can select the reported character set in the "Text import" dialog in Calc. If it is good, you could optionally save back out in "Unicode (UTF-8)", the default system character encoding in Ubuntu (and LibreOffice Calc).

**Background**

`.csv` files are ordinary text files. In a computer, characters are mapped to a sequence of bytes. Many characters use a single byte, but many more characters use a combination of bytes. The mapping is defined in a character set. Unfortunately, many character sets exist. A single one is used to encode your greek characters into a text file. The same character set is needed to translate the bytes in your text file back to the same greek characters.

A text file *only* contains the bytes making up the characters. Such file therefore does not contain any clue as to what character set was used to encode the file. In Linux, Unicode (UTF-8) is used by default. Applications may automatically guess the correct character code when opening a file encoded in a different set. If they do not guess the correct character set, many characters in the file may be rendered differently, including a question mark if an encoding does not match any character in the used character set.